# Why FileSavePicker is not replacing file?

Tags: c#, uwp, filesavepicker

when I used FileSavePicker to select (or create) storage file, if I select existing file, it will prompt for replace. when I press yes, I expect the file to be replaced later but it doesn't.

```
// existing file is picked, I pressed yes when replace was requested.
file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();
```

so with above code, existing file is picked by FileSavePicker, I expected that `file` is now replaced but its not.

```
await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite, StorageOpenOptions.AllowOnlyReaders)
```

This will only open file for write, it does not replace it, but I want it to be replaced. my issue is same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842374/how-can-i-overwrite-a-file-in-uwp), but I'm not writing text file, I'm writing binary data.

How can I replace `file` with new one?

Ive tried following but it throws NRE, because GetParentAsync is returning null.

```
var file = await (await file.GetParentAsync()).CreateFileAsync(file.Name,
                        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

I don't want user to explicitly create a new file by deleting old one and creating a new one. What I want is that if user selects existing file and accepts replace request from FileSavePicker, the file should be replaced.

---

Ok, here is code that you can test on your machine.

```
var picker = new FileSavePicker
{
    SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop,
    DefaultFileExtension = ".bin",
    SuggestedFileName = "Binary file"
};
picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Binary File", new List<string> {".bin"});

// in second run, choose existing file.
var file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();

using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite, StorageOpenOptions.AllowOnlyReaders))
{
    using (var output = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
    {
        using (var writer = new DataWriter(output))
        {
            writer.WriteBytes(Enumerable.Repeat<byte>(10, 10000).ToArray());
            await writer.StoreAsync();
            writer.DetachStream();
        }
        await output.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

Run this two times, in first run, create file. in second run select existing file, and also change `Repeat<byte>(10, 10000)` to something smaller and different, like `Repeat<byte>(80, 50)` and check content of file.

Comment: FileSavePicker does not replace files, it merely provides you with a name.  What you do *next* with that name matters.  File operations in WinRT are transactional, you can't accidentally overwrite a file.  Only when the file is correctly closed will it replace an existing file.  So the most important code is missing from the snippets.

Comment: right, how do I create a file with StorageFile that it gives to me? (then FileSavePicker is lying when its asking "replace with existing") @HansPassant

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying.  Post code that SO users can actually run themselves to verify your claims.

Comment: @HansPassant ive provided you sample, please test this code if you can and let me know what you observe. thank you.

Comment: WinRT doesn't have enough reasons to truncate the existing file.  Consider StorageFolder.CreateFileAsync so you can specify CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting

Comment: yes, I've tried that. but I cant get parent folder that user has chose the file within. for example desktop folder. I was thinking that `GetParentAsync` should give me the folder, and I create a file with same name and `ReplaceExisting` option. but parent is null I don't know why @HansPassant

Comment: @HansPassant I know we cant access everywhere for safety reasons, user must actively prompt access to something. but how am I going to replace file without telling user `"you must first remove it manually, then create a new one"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always [SetLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.setlength?view=netframework-4.7#System_IO_Stream_SetLength_System_Int64_) of your opened stream to 0 first - which will clear all the old content and set stream's position to 0. Afterwards you can just write to the stream your new content:

```
var picker = new FileSavePicker
{
    SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop,
    DefaultFileExtension = ".bin",
    SuggestedFileName = "Binary file"
};
picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Binary File", new List<string> { ".bin" });
var file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();

using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    stream.SetLength(0);
    var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Content");
    await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    await stream.FlushAsync();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I wonder why this has not been issue to anyone yet? it took me a day to realize that my app works without bug but its the old content that is messing with data reader.

Comment: I could also SetLength at end of write, `SetLength(bytesWritten)` so in case writer encounters problem, old data will not become lost.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Yes, *SetLength* will truncate or expand the stream if needed.